# Siegel's method for transcendence measure quoted by Mahler

Tags: reference-request, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

In "Zur Approximation der Exponentialfunktion und des Logarithmus. Teil II" Malher wrote (footnote 5 page 148) that the constant appearing in Satz 4 can be improved by a method communicated to him by Siegel. Does anyone know this method and where one can read it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The paper seems to be freely available at https://eudml.org/doc/183466

Comment: You gave the link for Part 1 of the article. The sentence is in Part 2. Anyway, I knew these links already. My question is: where can I find the Siegel's method, since it seems, following Mahler's quote, such a method exists. It is not in Mahler paper.

Comment: I think that the link I gave is for the issue of the journal that contains both Parts 1 and 2. I'm glad that you already knew these links, but then why didn't you include them in the body of your question, so that others not so fortunate as yourself would be able to access the paper easily?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, the [Kurt Mahler Archive](https://carmamaths.org/resources/mahler/collected.html) has pretty much all of Mahler's published works.